# What makes for a good upgrade experience for the end user in terms of release scope?

Tags: software, scope

I'm trying to come up with a point of view of what should be in scope for a quarterly release.

In my experience, some companies do upgrades very well. For example, upgrading to the latest Mac OS tends to go smoothly, triggers a guided tour, and introduces a combination of "under the hood" upgrades but also some noticeable UI&UX improvements.

Other upgrades have left me feeling like I had to do a lot of clicking and waiting for "security upgrades" that I wouldn't understand and seem to leave me with exactly the same UX. I'm not saying such releases aren't necessary, just that they lack identity.

Are there any golden rules? I'm not really looking for opinions so much as articles/posts that provide some rationale. I've searched but can only find guidance on how to release software, which is not what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The best software update is the absence of updates.

Let's figure it out together:
**Should the user know that the app has been updated?**

**1. No, there are no major updates.**
Just small security, UI, UX-copy, and other tweaks (updates do not affect the UX).
But still, we need to follow usability heuristic #1 (displaying system status), therefore the app via notification or another way should display a small, informative message like "The app updated. Everything is going well. [Dismiss]".
A good example of this is antivirus software.

**2. Yes, the last release impacts UX.**
It can be a new killing feature, some major user flow updates, etc.
So, for that, can be applied the onboarding process. Which should be as simple as possible and appears only by the User's confirmation (to go through that process).
Examples of it are Jira, Asana, Figma, any Adobe apps…

I reckon an onboarding process is a great tool, but it isn't one size fits all.
Should you consider whether it is worth the time for designers, developers and marketers?

More about onboarding:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-app-onboarding/
https://gregjeanneau.com/work/dashlane-case-study

Comment: That's a great answer Roman. I'm also interested in guidance on a good ratio of new features to usability improvements of existing features. I find there's a tendency to always release new features at the expense of improving what's already shipped.

Comment: Rob, as I see your question is about Product and UX strategy. So, I'm utterly convinced that you should talk over this topic with your Product Manager and/or CEO (or another top-level decision-maker).

I strongly agree that improving existing UX is pretty important, but what do your colleagues think?

Perfectly, you guys need to combine developing new things and maintaining old ones and then design a roadmap that needs to be based on the project's KPIs…

I would recommend listening to [Service Design Show](https://bit.ly/3kv3ium), maybe there you will find an answer.